# How do I tell folders not to open when available

Tags: windows-10, files-folders

I'm using W10. When I plug in a USB with lots of folders Windows opens all of the drives in a maximized form. How can I change that so the drives come up minimized?

Comment: Save Windows Explorer to work in Windowed Mode and not Full Screen and then this (above) should not happen)

Comment: Explorer is already set to windowed mode.

Comment: Try running the basic repair steps. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run first dism.exe  /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth    and then sfc /scannow .  Allow to complete, restart and test

Comment: it is not a repaire issue. It is an option. The option ususally shows up the first time a drive is inserted but once that is answered it does not ask again. I'm sure it is in settings but I can't find it.

Comment: I do not know of a setting that causes this issue

Comment: Using the option to "Do nothing" may result in the file not opening. That is the option part. That has nothing to do with the folder opening maximized.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out how to control this but today it did ask how to open the disks. I selected "do nothing".